# Good Validation Tool/Way for Migration from SQL Server 2008 R2 to 2016

Tags: sql-server, migration, upgrade

We're considering to upgrade SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition to 2016 or higher Version/Enterprise Edition.

We understand there are several validation and assistant tool, like Data Migration Assistant(DMA), but not sure what is the best solutions.

We'd like to validate especially as follows;

- DDL (Schema, Table, View, Trigger, Index)
- Stored procedures
- Functions
- SSIS Packages
- SQL scripts using by SSIS or sqlcmd/bcp utilities

I would be appreciated if you would share your useful experiences or any recommendable way to validate them. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This would be better suited for [dba.se] however simply asking for recommendations is going to likely get the question closed, you'll want to take their tour and ensure you can make this on topic for the community.

Comment: What's wrong with DMA? It is a tool for the task you have described.

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2012 R2** version - only **2012** - corrected

Comment: Start by fully understanding Database Compatibility Level. Short summary is that you don't certify databases to versions of SQL Server, you certify to DB Compat Levels. This helps reduce upgrade friction for SQL Server versions.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/database-engine/install-windows/compatibility-certification?WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001259&view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Denis Rubashkin  Many thanks, Denis. Just I'd like to check if there any other better solution. But I appreciated we could confirm DMA can solve our verifications.

Comment: @marc_s  You're right ...!  I mistyped SQL Server 2008 R2. Thanks for your correction.

Comment: @Martin Cairney  Thank you so much for your useful advice, Martin. I could learn a lot from your site, like 'DMA supports database compatibility level 100 and above.' I really appreciate it.